# Get Object Value from JSON Object in C#

Tags: c#, sql, json, xml

Here is the what I am trying to achieve here:

1. Get a list of file names and IDs from the database
2. Search for those files on a network path
3. Store any IDs of the files not found
4. Search for that ID in a second database
5. Search for those files on a network path
6. List all ID's where files are not found on either location.

The issue I an encountering is trying to use the file names from results I have collected.

When running the code, the raw JSON data collected from the database gets displayed, however when trying to list just the file names I get nothing (not even an error)

Any ideas on how to fix this and list the file names in a way that would also let me search for them later?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Also note: due to the version of SQL server being used i have to use FOR XML as FOR JSON is not compatible.

EDIT: Using code provided by Prany I am now able to output just the Audio File Name, but it I try and also output the sCallId I get a duplication Issue (see below output):

```
Getting Calls
2016\03\30\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf--84377-3668343241-514513
2016\03\30\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf--84385-3668343557-255773
2016\03\30\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf--84392-3668344445-516453
2016\03\30\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf--85000-3668749568-733799
2016\03\30\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf--85604-3668872399-722313
2016\03\30\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf--84377-3668343241-514513
2016\03\30\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf--84385-3668343557-255773
2016\03\30\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf--84392-3668344445-516453
2016\03\30\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf--85000-3668749568-733799
2016\03\30\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf--85604-3668872399-722313
2016\03\30\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf--84377-3668343241-514513
2016\03\30\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf--84385-3668343557-255773
2016\03\30\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf--84392-3668344445-516453
2016\03\30\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf--85000-3668749568-733799
2016\03\30\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf--85604-3668872399-722313
2016\04\04\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf--84377-3668343241-514513
2016\04\04\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf--84385-3668343557-255773
2016\04\04\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf--84392-3668344445-516453
2016\04\04\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf--85000-3668749568-733799
2016\04\04\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf--85604-3668872399-722313
2016\04\05\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf--84377-3668343241-514513
2016\04\05\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf--84385-3668343557-255773
2016\04\05\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf--84392-3668344445-516453
2016\04\05\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf--85000-3668749568-733799
2016\04\05\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf--85604-3668872399-722313
```

Below Is the code I am currently using to try and do this.

```
    //Run the SQL and wrap the output in results tags to fix Multiple Root Elements error. 
    string liveXML = "<results>" + cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString() + "</results>";
    //Create new XML Document
    XmlDocument LiveDoc = new XmlDocument();
    LiveDoc.LoadXml(liveXML);
    //Conver XML to JSON
    sjsonLive = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(LiveDoc);
    //Output RAW JSON
    txtOut.AppendText("\r\n" + sjsonLive); 
    //Parse JSON into an Array
    var files = JObject.Parse(sjsonLive);


    //We want to run this values in a files seach, but for now let's print it to txtOut
    foreach (var f in files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@audioFileName"))
    foreach (var c in files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@sCallID"))
    {
        txtOut.AppendText("\r\n" + f.ToString() + " - " + c.ToString());
        //Conduct File Search Here...
    }
```

Example JSON Data:

```
{
"results": {
    "calls": [{
            "@audioFileName": "2016\\03\\30\\300320161614210106361-00000934412405.asf",
            "@sCallID": "84377-3668343241-514513"
        }, {
            "@audioFileName": "2016\\03\\30\\300320161620220106362-00000934052048.asf",
            "@sCallID": "84385-3668343557-255773"
        }, {
            "@audioFileName": "2016\\03\\30\\300320161634220106363-00000933211384.asf",
            "@sCallID": "84392-3668344445-516453"
        }, {
            "@audioFileName": "2016\\04\\04\\040420160908190106389-00000527974488.asf",
            "@sCallID": "85000-3668749568-733799"
        }, {
            "@audioFileName": "2016\\04\\05\\050420161913220106406-00000405271715.asf",
            "@sCallID": "85604-3668872399-722313"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

You can use below token selector

```
files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@audioFileName")
```

edit 2:

```
 var calls = files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@sCallID").ToList();
 var audiofiles = files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@audioFileName").ToList();
 for (int i = 0; i <= audiofiles.Count; i++)
        {
            //Conduct File search 
            if (true)
            {
               //access by index like audiofiles[i] and append to the query
            }
            else
            {
             //access calls by index like calls[i] and append to the query

            }

        }
```

Comment: Since "results" is not an array, I think JArray.Parse will fail

Comment: Yeah when trying this I get the error "Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array"

Comment: @Prany This works and prints the "@audioFileName" value. Is there a way I can tweak this to also store "@sCallId" into a string called c?

Eg if file f does not exist add c to a "No File" list (That will then be used to query our 2nd database) and else output message saying file found

Comment: You can add another foreach for sCallID inside the first foreach.. files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@sCallID")

Comment: @Prany This works.. sort of so might be doing something wrong here as for for each file it see's all 5 call ids.


Eg. 

File 1 - Callid 1
File 1 - Callid 2
etc


`foreach (var f in files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@audioFileName"))
foreach (var c in files.SelectTokens("$..calls..@sCallID"))
            {
                txtOut.AppendText("\r\n" + f.ToString() + " - " + c.ToString());
                //Conduct File Search Here...
            }`

Comment: Do you want all callid inside your json ?

Comment: I am looking to use the Audio File Name to check if the file exists in a specified path. If it doesn't exist add the corresponding callid to a list for use in a query against a second database. I could do this by running a new query each time, but this could lead to a high number of queries being run, where at the moment it's only running this one query.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check

Comment: Had to change "for (int i = 0; i <= audiofiles.Count; i++)" to "for (int i = 0; i < audiofiles.Count; i++)" but this worked! Thanks for the help