# How to load JSON Class Schema with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, jsonschema

I used to use a converter to convert JSON Schema to C# code and then copy & paste the C# code to my Visual Studio project. Now I wonder if I can just copy & paste the JSON schema to my Visual Studio project directly so that the schema will be parsed automatically and the classes from the schema are ready to use (so I don't have to do it manually, and keep the JSON schema itself as the single source of truth).

Note: This is not about parsing JSON, please refer to JSON Schema http://json-schema.org/

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunatelly there is not such an option, however you can use JSON.NET that already 100 Million+ are using it. you can Serialize and deserialize with a single line of code and its available via nuget with a click.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: imagine you have list of a class (in a variable named myobj) and it has arrays and other classes as its properties. `string json = JsonConvert.Seralize(myobj);` and you can have the json string. to convrt it back `List<YourClass> myobj = JsonCovert.Deserialize<List<Yourclass>>(json);`

Comment: its hard using cell phone.If you like i can give live examples tomorrow from my pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newton Soft JSON to serialize and deserialize json. Few examples are

[Get Object Value from JSON Object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705546/get-object-value-from-json-object-in-c-sharp/50705722#50705722)

[Json path query in JObject.SelectTokens in Json.net not returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738180/json-path-query-in-jobject-selecttokens-in-json-net-not-returning-results/50738726#50738726)